# Laravel mail, can't pass variable into subject but it works in the body

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sending a simple email that needs to use a variable in both the body and the subject. It works fine passing the variable into the body, but it fails on my subject line and says undefined variable

```
$body = "Attached is the " .$name. " Report for ".date('Y-m-d');
Mail::raw($body , function ($message) use ($emails,$filepath,$filename) {
    $message->from('noreply@test.com', 'webmail');
    $message->attach(storage_path($filepath.'/'.$filename.'.xlsx'));
    foreach ($emails['to'] as $email) {
        $message->to($email);
    }
    foreach ($emails['cc'] as $email) {
        $message->cc($email);
    }
    $message->subject("Report for " .$name. " account");
});
```

Why is it using it in the body but not the subject here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the name into the use statement of the function.

Its not defined as its not passed into the callback function.

```
Mail::raw($body , function ($message) use ($emails,$filepath,$filename,$name) {
```

Comment: And there is a reason why I stopped helping people on Stack overflow, downvoted for giving the correct answer xD

Comment: I know the feeling! I'm throwing you an upvote and an accept because it works, though! Thank you very much, I"m not very familiar with the Mail usage in laravel honestly

Comment: Its because its using a callback function, so to access the variables you need to explicitly define them in the use statement.  In a way its like saying function($name), but as you are not calling the function in a traditional way you cant do that so you have to define them in a use statement to be able to use them

Comment: Makes perfect sense, and now I'll never forget it. That was just a pesky error that I couldn't seem to get through for some reason. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, glad I could help out.  Don't forget to mark as the correct answer to further annoy the down voters xD